# SwiftUI & CoreData: Error when passing FetchedResults to subview (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

Everything is running fine on debug, but when I switch it to release I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, ...)` Error. I narrowed the issue down to a subview to which I pass a `FetchedResult` sub property. Here's how the views look like and the data is loaded and passed on:

List with `NavigationLink`s, here a `@FetchRequest` is made to get `M_ScoreSession`s:

```
struct V_Home: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: M_ScoreSession.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \M_ScoreSession.date, ascending: false)]) var scoreSessions: FetchedResults<M_ScoreSession>
    ...
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
        ForEach(Array(scoreSessions.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (i, scoreSession) in
            NavigationLink(destination: V_SessionDetail(scoreSession: scoreSession)) {
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        V_ScoreSessionListItem(scoreSession: scoreSession)
                    }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

DetailView, showing cards for each `M_PersonScore`:

```
struct V_SessionDetail: View {
    @ObservedObject var scoreSession: M_ScoreSession
    ...
    var body: some View {
        Text(scoreSession.wGame.wName)  // < accessing properties here works no problem
        ...
        ForEach(Array(scoreSession.wPersonScores.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (i, personScore) in
            V_ScoreCard( // < this line shows this Error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0xd00..."
                scoreSession.wGame.wScoreTemplate,
                personScore
            )
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This is the subview that's causing the error/crash:

```
struct V_ScoreCard: View {
    @ObservedObject var personScore: M_PersonScore
    @ObservedObject var scoreTemplate: M_ScoreTemplate
    ...
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(self.personScore.score)") // < accessing properties of personScore or scoreTemplate causes the crash
    }
}
```

When I remove the `V_ScoreCard`, there's no problem. When I leave it in and run the project with "Build Configuration: Debug" there's no problem. I don't have much experience with memory debugging, but I've tried what's proposed in [this article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544) and other similar ones.

Am I doing something wrong loading the data via the `@FetchRequest`? Or passing the data to the first or the second subview?

If the problem could be somewhere else I'm happy to zip up the project and share it. I have no clue whatsoever what to do about this.

UPDATE:
[Here's a zip of the whole project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3pzxivuc0xaoky2/AADXb0SyflQFWL7pMgHkJyHVa?dl=0)

To reproduce the crash, the build setting should be "release". Tap the plus button, enter a Game name, add a person and create the session. Then, on the list tap the list item and it should crash.

Comment: Can you show the injected CoreData "Managed Object Context" in the environment, and specifically, which execution context it is using (it MUST be executing on the main thread)? See here: [CoreData & SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-access-a-core-data-managed-object-context-from-a-swiftui-view). If this was your issue, all credit goes to Paul Hudson! ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I'm doing it exactly the same way Paul Hudson is doing it. Also, it's working on debug so I don't think the syntax is the problem.

Comment: Is your Managed Object Context associated to the _main thread_? This is important. It can lead to the crashes if it executes on a different thread. The UI needs it on the main thread. There are also CoreData debugging options (process environment variables, settable in Xcode Scheme)  which you may enable.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I am using `NSPersistentContainer` and I'm assuming it's creating the `NSManagedObjectContext` on the main thread. Also, I've attached the full project now. Maybe that helps. I'll have a look at the debugging options for CoreData, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, confirmed: it runs on the main thread. So, there's an issue elsewhere.

Comment: I encountered sever other issues when running it. It takes 100% CPU time, please take a look with the profiler. Hint: I saw several occurrences where you initialise a StateObject in the initialiser, which is an anti pattern, but can be more harmful - especially, when you think it is doing this in the initialiser - but it does completely skip the effect, if the conceptual view is already existent.

Comment: @couchdeveloper I‘ll have a look at that as well, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Considering the complexity of the project, you may consider to switch to a unidirectional event driven approach. Your views would become dumb and just render a const "view state" which they observe and which has been set by the parent view. They forward user actions only via callback variables also set by the parent. All logic can be moved to the "view model" which is indeed just a thin wrapper connecting a "Store" which performs the mutations based on the current model state and the current event, and also invoking "side effects" (CoreData calls). Your ViewState is simply a function of state.

Comment: Just tried on low end iPhone simulator and could not get it to work as per CouchDeveloper.  More success on the iPad 8th gen simulator, however it didn't crash on clicking the list item in the release build. In both case there was enormous amount of messages being printed to Xcode's console about 'malloc' failing, LayoutConstraints being unsatisfiable etc.  fwiw Rather than worrying about the code here, if it was my app I'd want to address those messages as they smell of memory leaks/excessive recursion, which would cause exactly the type of release/debug weirdness being seen. Good luck.

Comment: @couchdeveloper I‘ve tried following the mvvm model from the beginning but I guess I wasn‘t doing things correctly because I couldn’t get it to work. Accessing sub properties never really seemed to work for (update) my view models (ObservedObject) and since this is a prototype I eventually gave up and returned to using State variables which at least worked. I also found it difficult to find information about how to properly do all that.

Comment: @shufflingb maybe I don’t have the right diagnostics enables but I’m not seeing these kinds of messages

Comment: I was seeing the messages with Xcode 13 beta 5. Just tried with Xcode 12.5.1  and don't see the messages. Also iPhone works and then blows up as described.

Comment: @shufflingb I‘m still using Xcode 12, I‘ll have a look at that later on. I appreciate you taking a look though, thanks :)

Comment: MVVM suggests to have a View which renders a const "view state" and user actions (including parameters) will be send to the view model. It would not have a `@FetchRequest` for example. Your View Model would have a layer "Model" which internally _may_ use CoreData. Basically a ViewModel takes input events and publishes a ViewState. Internally, a VM may use a Finite State Machine (event driven Actor) which mutates its internal "State" and optionally calling external "Effects" communicating with the outside world (CoreData, UserPrefs, Network, Int.random, print, log, etc).

Comment: In your project, the Model is tightly coupled via View Bindings and also integrated into the view (the view creates the VM). Using Bindings in VMs is not a good idea since this creates a multitude of dependencies, and SwiftUI tries to resolve them. Actually, your model depends on "parent state" in addition to the view's state via _Bindings_. That can cause recursive or infinite loops far too easy. A unidirectional approach prevents this (V sends event E to VM, VM generates ViewState). It will be very interesting to refactor this and experience the clarity the project gains through this :)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper that definitely sounds like something I'd like to do. Do you know of any good example projects or articles explaining how to do all that in SwiftUI in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

could you try this:

```
struct V_ScoreCard: View {
    @ObservedObject var scoreTemplate: M_ScoreTemplate
    @ObservedObject var personScore: M_PersonScore
    ....
```

Also instead of "enumerated" try this, in case the array is not zero-based:

```
ForEach(Array(zip(scoreSession.wPersonScores.indices, scoreSession.wPersonScores)), id: \.0) { (i, personScore) in
```

Comment: I suspect, there is an explicit init for V_ScoreCard, like `init(_ scoreTemplate: M_ScoreTemplate , _ personScore: M_PersonScore)`.

Comment: yeah probably, it's just my lucky day.

Comment: @workingdog there's an explicit init for `V_ScoreCard`, so the order is not the problem as CouchDeveloper assumed. The ForEach with zip also doesn't make a difference. I've tried `scoreSession.wPersonScores[i]` as well. The odd thing is that it's all working perfectly on debug, so I don't think it's a syntax problem.

Comment: as a test, how about removing "@ObservedObject " from those two things in " V_ScoreCard"

Comment: @workingdog When I do that, the crash is still happening but the message now says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,...)" instead of "code=257", and the line it's showing the error is now at "@main". I've attached the whole project now, so maybe that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a very dumb solution and I don't know why this works, but instead of getting the properties first and passing them, I now pass the whole object and only access the properties in the child view:

DetailView:

```
struct V_SessionDetail: View {
    @ObservedObject var scoreSession: M_ScoreSession
    ...
    var body: some View {
        Text(scoreSession.wGame.wName)
        ...
        ForEach(Array(scoreSession.wPersonScores.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (i, personScore) in
            V_ScoreCard(
                scoreSession, // < passing the parent
                i             // < passing the index
            )
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Child View:

```
struct V_ScoreCard: View {
    @ObservedObject var personScore: M_PersonScore
    @ObservedObject var scoreTemplate: M_ScoreTemplate
    
    init(_ scoreSession: M_ScoreSession,
         _ personScoreIndex: Int) {
        // getting the properties in the child
        let personScore = scoreSession.wPersonScores[personScoreIndex]
        self.scoreTemplate = scoreSession.wGame.wScoreTemplate
    }
    ...
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(self.personScore.score)")
    }
}
```

So far it's solving the crashes, although I have a slightly bad feeling about this. If someone knows what's actually going on here and how to properly fix this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 12 with 14.5**

What's causing the crash in the original VScoreCard looks like a bug and is to do with the way that the state score variable is being initialised.

VScoreCard currently looks something like this ...

```
@State var score: String

...

init(_ scoreTemplate: M_ScoreTemplate, _ personScore: M_PersonScore, isSelected: Bool, selection: Binding<Int?>, showScoreOperands: Binding<Bool>) {
    self.personScore = personScore

    ...

    self.score = personScore.score.clean // <== Crashes on this assignment
```

What appears to be happening is that `score` is not ready to be assigned inside `init` via `self.score`.  I think this a bug with SwiftUI as it works fine in Xcode 13 with ios 14.5 and 15.0.

Anyway, the workaround is as follows in VScoreCard:

```
@State var score: String = ""

...

self._score.wrappedValue = personScore.score.clean
```

**Xcode 13 probs**

Whilst chasing down the above, I encountered another unrelated problem with Xcode 13 (beta 5) that caused lockups when trying to add a new session by repeatedly re-rendering V_NewSessionView. The problem is being triggered by V_FocusableTextField using its own `onFocused` mechanism. As if it's noop'd out (`self.onFocused = {}`) it all works fine. My guess as to why is that using the wrapped UITextField's focus may be conflicting with the new built in focus mechanism.

Good luck with the App